# Unable to read json feed with json_decode

Tags: php, json

I am using Facebook open graph as json feed format to get the page name after I provide an access token in the URL.

here is my code:

```
$get_pages = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=".$_POST['access_token']);
$get_pages = json_decode($get_pages);

foreach($get_pages->data as $page){
    echo $page[name];
    }
```

I am trying to echo the name of the pages. The Json code that Facebook provide looks like this:

```
 {
       "data": [
          {
             "category": "website",
             "name": "jjj",
             "access_token": "jjj",
             "id": "jjj",
             "perms": [
                "jjj",
                "jjj",
                "jjj",
                "jjj",
                "jjj",
                "jjj"
             ]
          },
          {
             "category": "Community",
             "name": "ggg",
             "access_token": "ggg",
             "id": "ggg",
             "perms": [
                "ggg",
                "ggg",
                "ggg",
                "ggg",
                "ggg",
                "ggg"
             ]
          }
],
   "paging": {
      "next": "hhh"
   }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
    catchable fatal error: object of class stdclass could not be converted to string in
with this line of code :$get_pages = json_decode($get_pages);
```

what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: You're mixing array and object access. Use `json_decode($data, TRUE)` to get an all-array result for `["page"]` in the foreach and `["name"]` for entries. Else use `->name`. See also http://array.include-once.org/

Comment: Are you sure that this is the correct line number? I've tested it with your data and it worked with no errors. (Cannot really believe that the error is on that line)

Comment: I solved my question. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it :) I changed my code to this:

```
$get_pages = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=".$_POST['access_token']);
$get_pages = json_decode($get_pages, TRUE);
echo '<select id="select_page">';
foreach($get_pages[data] as $page_name){
echo '<option>'.$page_name[name].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```